# Can't get supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow to work with Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

Hey Stackoverflow Members, 
maybe you could help me to get my problem fixed.

The problem is I want to lock the orientation for all UIViewControllers to "Portrait" but if the MoviePlayer appears it should switch into landscape mode and back if the movie player disappears.

Until Swift 1.2 I used:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
//If the video is being presented, let the user change orientation, otherwise don't.
if let presentedViewController = window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController? {
    if (presentedViewController.isKindOfClass(MPMoviePlayerViewController) && !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed()) {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    }
}
return .Portrait
}
```

With Swift 1.2 some things changed and so I ended up with the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    //If the video is being presented, let the user change orientation, otherwise don't.
    if let presentedViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        if (presentedViewController.isKindOfClass(MPMoviePlayerViewController) && !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed()) {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        }
    }
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

But my code doesn't work, the Movie Player (XCDYoutube) is locked in portrait mode. Device orientation Settings should be fine!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have two quick suggestions:

1. Make sure your Info.plist file for your project does not contain a key for supported interface orientation that excludes landscape modes.
2. Set a breakpoint at the first 'if' statement line in your supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow function and then just single step thru the code to see what is happening.

Comment: further to deanware's comments - are you sure its hitting the breakpoint?  You're returning an int / not UIInterfaceOrientationMask. Did you try the upgrade to swift 1.2 menu option?

Comment: I just tried in a new project your Swift 1.2 code and it works fine. The app only rotates when the MoviePlayer is presented. You probably have another problem. Maybe the XCDYoutube is not playing nice with iOS 8 and not rotating anymore? Try to return All orientations all the time to see if the movie player rotates.

Comment: Stupid, but with me, check the rotation is lock in my device :)

Answer (score 3):

I had similar logic to yours but ending up returning support for all orientations.

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll in appdelegate.

Depending on how many view controllers you have - you may want to create an abstract subclass of UIViewController and return only support for Portrait / and then hack your youtube view controller to support landscape.

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
  }

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same issue. I found a way to fix it by reaching the top of the controller stack:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    //If the video is being presented, let the user change orientation, otherwise don't.
    if var presentedViewController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
        // Get the controller on the top of the stack
        while (presentedViewController.presentedViewController) != nil {
            presentedViewController = presentedViewController.presentedViewController!
        }

        if (presentedViewController.isKindOfClass(MPMoviePlayerViewController) && !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed()) {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        }
    }
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

You can also try to display the type of `presentedViewController` to be sure it's the right one:

```
println("presentedViewController type: \(presentedViewController.dynamicType)")
```